# How to save Selected Radio Button out of Toggle group to MySQL Database JavaFx

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, phpmyadmin, radio-button

I need to save the user's selected gender out of a gender Toggle group with the options 'M' and 'F' to a localhost phpmyadmin database. I have created the Radio Buttons in Scenebuilder, but the Sql commands to retrieve the user's selected Radiobutton are not working.

I've tried using the .getSelectedToggle() method to retrieve the user's choice from the toggle group, but it isn't working. The entire run fails because of this problem.

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into"
    + "alumni(aFirstName,aLastName,aGender,aBirthDate,aGradYear,aIndustry,"
    + "aProfession,aEmail,aLiveInGhana,aMailAddress)"
    + "values('"+firstName.getText()+"','"+lastName.getText()+
           "','"+gender.getSelectedToggle()+"','"+
           "','"+birthdate.getValue()+"','"+
           "','"+gradyear.getValue()+"','" +industry.getText()+
           "','"+profession.getText()+"','"+email.getText()+
           "','"+liveInGh.g()+"','"+mailAdd.getText()+"')");
```

When the user saves their information, the selected toggle from toggle group 'gender' should be saved to the 'aGender' field in the alumni table.

Comment: You're using `PreparedStatement` but are still concatenating the parameters into the SQL. You should put placeholders (`?`) in the SQL query, such as `select * from users where id = ?`. You then call the appropriate `setXXX` methods on the `PreparedStatement` to set the parameters. See [_Using Prepared Statements_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Comment: try to provide the code creating the toggle group and the error message so we can define the problem if you are using scene builder provide the fxml code

Comment: @AhmedEmad the only code for creating the toggle group is from the controller skeleton code made in Scenebuilder ; `private ToggleGroup gender`